# Xamarin Failed loading bitmap in skiasharp

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, skiasharp

I have a problem. I am trying to load an image, so I use this code:

```
string resourceID = "MyApp.Templates.Good_Question.png";
Assembly assembly = GetType().GetTypeInfo().Assembly;

using (Stream stream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream(resourceID))
{
    bitmap = SKBitmap.Decode(stream);
}
```

But it gives an error on stream, because stream is null. Now I created a folder in the root of the app called Templates and placed an image called Good_Question.png in the folder.

Why is my stream null?

Comment: Is the image flagged with a compile type of "Resource"?

Comment: Not yet, going to try now

Comment: stream is still null?

Comment: are the images in the same project as this code?  Do they have the correct build action?  Are you sure that you are using the correct ResourceID?

Comment: The folder is created in the root directory, so in MyApp. Not in MyApp.Android or MyApp.iOS. The build action of the image Good_Question.png is set to Resource.

Comment: @A.Vreeswijk Right click in the image and check resource id to make sure it matches (you can also override the naming if needed).

Comment: Where can I see the Resource Id? I can click on Properties, but there is no ResourceId

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/images?tabs=windows#embedded-images

Comment: I found it, I had to set the Build Action to Embedded Resource, not Resource

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found it, I had to set the Build Action to Embedded Resource, not Resource